# How to display subcolumns under a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have created a single column whose heading is "January". Under this column i wanna add 
subcolumns whose headings are "Rent", "Food", "Others"..

so please suggest me some query in mysql..

I am expecting my answer to be as shown below,

```
-----------------------------
         January
-----------------------------
| Rent  |  Food  |  Others  |
|       |        |          |
|       |        |          |
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually i am not getting any idea.. I need a query to create a subcolumns under a single column..

Comment: Are you asking how to do a particular query, or how to get the SQL command line to output results that look exactly that way? I don't think the SQL command line offers many options for formatting, though I could be wrong.

Comment: I am asking how to do a particular query

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the data storage layer (ie. SQL) instead of the presentation layer (application interface, report, etc)?

Comment: oh sorry i came to know it is not possible to create as my requirement in mysql.. So please let me know, is it possible to create the same in jaspersoft ireport??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible, you could create a table called January and then add columns rent, food, others. Are you using a php form to input the values, then use a table to view the submitted results?

Comment: No, i am using mysql.. I need the same thing from january to december.

Comment: oh sorry i came to know it is not possible to create as my requirement in mysql.. So please let me know, is it possible to create the same in jaspersoft ireport??

Comment: Sory I have never used jaspersoft ireport before. I'm creating a mysql database at the moment, and presenting it on a html table using php. If you planned on doing the same then could create a form that allows you to insert data into your mysql database which goes to 12 tables you have created lablled with the 12 months and then use PHP to present that data onto an HTML table, then you could use jpgraph to create any graphs you require etc.